# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Tags: swift, xcode10, swift4.1.5

After updating to Xcode 10 beta, which apparently comes with Swift 4.1.50, I'm seeing the following error which I'm not sure how to fix:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range< String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range< String.Index>)'

in the following function at `Range<Index>(start..<self.endIndex)` (line 3):

```
func index(of aString: String, startingFrom position: Int? = 0) -> String.Index? {
    let start: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: position!)
    let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>(start..<self.endIndex)
    return self.range(of: aString, options: .literal, range: range, locale: nil)?.lowerBound
}
```

Any idea how to fix the initializer?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### Some background:

In Swift 3, additional range types were introduced, making a total
of four (see for example [Ole Begemann: Ranges in Swift 3](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/)):

```
Range, ClosedRange, CountableRange, CountableClosedRange
```

With the implementation of [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) in Swift 4.2, the “countable” variants
are not separate types anymore, but (constrained) type aliases, for example

```
 public typealias CountableRange<Bound: Strideable> = Range<Bound>
      where Bound.Stride : SignedInteger
```

and, as a consequence, various conversions between the different
range types have been removed, such as the

```
init(_ other: Range<Range.Bound>)
```

initializer of `struct Range`. All theses changes are part of the
[[stdlib][WIP] Eliminate (Closed)CountableRange using conditional conformance (#13342)](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/9ee856f386f9be65234e25038a91a34fa07acacd) commit.

So that is the reason why

```
let range: Range<Index> = Range<Index>(start..<self.endIndex)
```

does not compile anymore.

#### How to fix

As you already figured out, this can be simply fixed as

```
let range: Range<Index> = start..<self.endIndex
```

or just

```
let range = start..<self.endIndex
```

without the type annotation.

Another option is to use a *one sided range*
(introduced in Swift 4 with [SE-0172 One-sided Ranges](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md)):

```
extension String {
    func index(of aString: String, startingFrom position: Int = 0) -> String.Index? {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: position)
        return self[start...].range(of: aString, options: .literal)?.lowerBound
    }
}
```

This works because the substring `self[start...]` *shares its indices*
with the originating string `self`.

Comment: your index function does not compile

Comment: @user3561494: It compiles for me. Which Xcode version are you using? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out, ranges do not have to be initialized but can simply be created as follows:

```
let range: Range<Index> = start...end
```

In this case, the code would be fixed by replacing `Range<Index>(start..<self.endIndex)` with:

```
let range: Range<Index> = start..<self.endIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, You can use this code to fix the issue -

**let range = startIndex ..< characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)**

Reference : https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport/issues/121

Answer (score 1):

I migrated from xcode 9.2 to xcode 10.1 and then started facing this error and resolved by this way

`let range = start...end`