# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Tags: range, swift4, xcode10

> Since Xcode 10 I receive an error message `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'` at the return line in the code below, which is an extension used to get a substring when needed.

I have found another good answer given by Martin R at [Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o), but didn't find a way yet to fix my problem.

```
extension String {
    subscript (i: Int) -> Character { return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)] }
    subscript (i: Int) -> String { return String(self[i] as Character) }
        subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound)

        return String(self[Range(start ..< end)])
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `Range( )` as described in the linked answer. `return String(self[start ..< end])`.

Comment: Thanks OOPer!  It worked.  Obviously I was looking in the wrong direction.