# Extraneous argument label 'with:' in call

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

In this code

`text = prospectiveText.substring( with: Range<String.Index>(prospectiveText.startIndex ..< prospectiveText.characters.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)) )`

i get the error `Extraneous argument label 'with:' in call` after I updated xcode to 10.01

How to fix the bug?

Comment: Remove the extraneous label?

Comment: @Paulw11 after removing it, I get `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'` this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o), the compiler error can be fixed by removing the `Range<String.Index>(...)` conversion. This will still cause warnings

> 'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly
>   substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript.

which can be fixed with

```
text = prospectiveText[..<prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)]
```

However, you can achieve the same result far simpler with

```
text = String(prospectiveText.prefix(maxLength))
```