# Substring using Range

Tags: swift, range, substring

```
// Substring
func substring(_ start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    return self.substring(with: Range(self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start) ..< self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: end)))
}
```

Getting the below error in that return statement after updating Xcode to 10.0. Let me know how can I show the return statement according to latest swift version.

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of
>   type '(Range)'

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you're using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o)

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 10 you can choose between Swift 3, Swift 4 and Swift 4.2 versions.
I assume that you mean Swift 4.2 when you are talking about the latest Swift version. Keep in your mind that `substring(with:)` function has deprecated since Swift 4, so you could use string slicing:

```
extension String {
    func substring(_ start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
        let endIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: end)
        return String(self[startIndex...endIndex])
    }
}
```