# Error cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Tags: swift

Why do I get the error, Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range)'

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return Character("")
        }

        if i > self.characters.count {
            return Character("")
        }

        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        if self.isEmpty {
            return ""
        }

        if i > self.characters.count {
            return ""
        }

        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
        let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        return self[Range(start ..< end)]
    }

}
```

Comment: What Swift version are you using? `.characters` have been deprecated in Swift 4

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o