# Unable to invoke initializer for type 'Range<_>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'

Tags: ios, swift

I have referred many solutions provided through below links, but not getting the idea. Still facing this issue. Please refer to the picture and help me out. Thanks!

```
   subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
//        let end = <#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to `start`##String.CharacterView#>.index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)

        let range: Range<Index> = start..<end

        return String(self[range])
    }
```

[Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<String.Index>' with an argument list of type '(Range<String.Index>)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714543/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-rangestring-index-with-an-argument-list-o)

[image]

Comment: Please post *code,* not screenshots.

Comment: posted the code, plz check

Comment: Previous code:

  subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
//        let end = <#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to `start`##String.CharacterView#>.index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        return String(self[(start..<end)])
    }

Comment: Your code compiles without problems in Xcode 10.1 (Swift 4).

Comment: This is failing in XCode Version 10.0, Do I need to update XCode? shouldn't it support over there too.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it got fixed:

String.swift was a pod library with the code patch above. So here what I did.

Xcode -> File -> WorkSpace -> Buil System -> Select Legacy Build System

And it got compiled successfully.

[image]

Thanks!